# Как сделать резиновую картинку на одной линии с текстом?

Tags: html, css

При этом текст не должен не должен обтекать картинку как при использовании `float`.

Cделал при помощи CSS таблиц: https://jsfiddle.net/5p1fLuop/

Нормально или можно упростить?

Answer (score 1):

Можно не менять теги, всё сделать через стили.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
}

#a {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}

#b {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id='a'>
    <img src='..path/img.jpg'>
    <div id='b'>Привет мистер бобёр!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Примените элемент **figcaption** из стандарта ХТМЛ5:

```
<figure style=text-align:center>
    <img style=max-width:100% src='http://webmandry.com/images/stories/2013/03/013-biver/3.jpg'>
    <figcaption style=font-family:Verdana>Привет мистер бобёр!</figcaption>
</figure>
```